# Store large data at the end of python source

Tags: python

How to read data from the end of the source file?

The only way that I have thought of to do this would be to reopen the source from within the program and reading the source as text. There has to be code to deal with `.pyc` files.

Is there an easier, more pythonic way to do this? I suppose it might involve some way to make a forward reference in a python source file, like this (which doesn't work).

```
test_data = gettestdata()
for d in data:
    # do all kinds of stuff in may lines of code

def gettestdata():
    return \
        (many lines of data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that everything should be inside functions/classes, so the main function exists only for parsing parameters, initiating loggers and other non functional stuff.

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def run(input_data):
    return input_data


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # initiate loggers
    # make other things

    data = "qqqqqqqqqq" \
           "wwwwwwwwwww" \
           "eeeeeeeeeee"

    result = run(data)

    print(result)
```

**Output**

> qqqqqqqqqqwwwwwwwwwwweeeeeeeeeee

Is it what you want? If not, sorry, I do not know other 'pythonic' ways.

Answer (score 1):

You have one or more "large" strings to fetch, such as SQL CREATE TABLE statements.
Bury each one in a getter, using triple-quote syntax.
For example:

```
def get_create_foo():
    return """
create table foo (
  id integer primary key,
  ...
);
    """
```

Then a call like

```
    session.execute(get_create_foo())
```

is a nice compact one-liner.

For test data, you might want to `.split()` or otherwise massage your data so it's easy to iterate over.
For large test data, it probably belongs in a separate file, such as a CSV.
Consider pulling it in with [`.from_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), which is quite convenient.

Remember that `__file__` can tell you where your script is running.
(There are some edge cases, such as when the script is in a .zip on your $PYTHONPATH.)
Here is a standard idiom for finding a CSV in the same folder as your source code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

folder = Path(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
with open(folder / 'foo.csv') as file_in:
    ...
```